# What are the considerations for placing brushless motor controllers in parallel by syncing the PWM output?

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

If I have two identical brushless ESCs, and I would like to mate their outputs up in parallel in order to have something approaching 2x current handling, what kind of challenges need to be met in order to sync up their PWM outputs?

Ignoring niceties such as switching from open-loop to closed-loop control during the startup, from my naive first-order understanding it seems that the only concern is that PWM outputs have to stay synced to a small fraction of the FET deadtime. If that deadtime is around 80ns, then anything better than 20ns would suffice, AFAIU.

- Is this correct?
- How sensitive is the wiring for this in a high-current (~400A) environment?

  - Assume shielded wires of a known length (for estimating propagation delay).
- Lastly, assuming STM32F4 at 168MHz, is this realistically possible?

P.S. The application is for an airplane propeller. This is why we can ignore the startup considerations, since we don't have any low-and-slow torque needs.

Comment: All - The long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore it has been moved to chat and should be continued there (link below). --- As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per question, any further comments posted here might be deleted without notice. **Keep it in chat now, please!** When someone has got enough information from the chat to post an answer, then please do that as usual. Any updates to the question which are decided during the chat, should be made via an edit to the question and not left in a comment. Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130852/discussion-on-question-by-kenn-sebesta-what-are-the-considerations-for-placing-b).